# Checking for existence for a field on an an entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: entities

I am iterating through a field collection, and wrapping the field collection items with an entity_metadata_wrapper. I would like to check for the existence of field before calling its `value` method (which results in an error on fields that do not have a value), but I cannot find a way to do so.

```
$field_collection_item = field_collection_item_load($id);
$item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);

// this results in an error if the field_contrib_headshot field is empty
$headshot = $item_wrapper->field_contributor->field_contrib_headshot->value();
```

My current workaround is to use `field_get_items` to see if the field is empty, but i'd love to be able to do this through the metadata wrapper if possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply call the PHP function [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
$headshot = array();
if (isset($item_wrapper->field_contributor->field_contrib_headshot)) {
  $headshot = $item_wrapper->field_contributor->field_contrib_headshot->value();
}
```

EntityStructureWrapper implements the `__isset()` function according the principe of [Overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Comment: Yes, this is always how I've done it, less tied into the internals and easier to read IMO. Upvoted!

Answer (score 9):

Any time there is an entity reference or field collection, isset() has *never* worked for me. What does seem to work any time we have an entity reference is doing:

```
if($wrapped_entity->entity_reference_field->getIdentifier()) {
  // This code only fires if there is an entity reference or field collection set.
}
```

Comment: This answer and the following post worked for me: http://dropbucket.org/node/1201

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have an `entity_reference` somewhere in there due to the method chaining. But, look at the [__isset() method for EntityStructureWrapper](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityStructureWrapper%3a%3a__isset/7).

Check like:

```
$has_headshot = $item_wrapper->field_contributor->__isset('field_contrib_headshot');
```

and then use an `IF` block to do your logic ...

**EDIT:**

`$has_headshot` is now valid check desired.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks like you have an entity reference somewhere", if you could explain that a little more i'd appreciate it. ``__isset`` works great on the field collection, although I need to add the full field name: ``field_contrib_headshot`` instead of ``contrib_headshot``

Comment: fields are values; a string, a number, whatever. `field_contributor` is referencing another field `field_contrib_headshot` ... you have nesting in there somehow. I'm assuming you're using entity_reference or something else like field_group to nest these things ... thats all I meant.

Comment: what was the __isset() piece of code that worked for you ?

Comment: It was: ``$item_wrapper->field_contributor->__isset('field_contrib_headshot')``

Comment: It feels weird to me to call the __isset() directly, why not:

`$has_headshot = isset($item_wrapper->field_contributor->field_contrib_headshot);`

Comment: did you read the code in the documentation i linked? http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityStructureWrapper%3a%3a__isset/7  that code does call isset(), but if the Object is not fully loaded isset() will not work as expected. The __isset() magic method lazy loads the entities properties if they aren't loaded by the system yet to safely perform this check.

Answer (score 1):

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', 123);
if($wrapper->__isset('field_middle_name')) {
    // Do something awesome with the middle name.
} else {
    // Don't do anything awesome, they don't have a middle name.
}
```

Entity reference fields and field collections

```
// also check if there is an identifier, __isset alone is not enough!
if ($wrapper->__isset('field_project_number') && $wrapper->field_project_number->getIdentifier()) {
    $number =  $wrapper->field_project_number->field_project_number_complete->value();
    return $number;
}
```

Copied and pasted straight from http://dropbucket.org/node/1201 but seems to be a better example than any other answer so far...

Answer (score 1):

For EntityMetadataWrapper:

If you've got blocks of code running that shouldn't or if you've come across PHP errors look at some of the examples below. This example uses the property nid.

MAY ALL ERROR

```
if ($wrapper->__isset('nid')) {
  $var = $wrapper->nid->value();
}
else {
  // Do something it's FALSE;
}
```

OR

```
if ($wrapper->__isset('nid')) {
  $var = $wrapper->nid->getIdentifier();
}
else {
  // Do something it's FALSE;
}
```

OR

```
if ($wrapper->nid->value()) {
  // Do something it's TRUE.
}
else {
  // Do something it's FALSE;
}
```

You may find that using isset like so might evaluate to true even if the nid is not present. The ->getIdentifier(), or ->value(), or ->raw() may throw exceptions.

LIKELY ALWAYS TRUE

```
if (isset($wrapper->nid)) {
  // Do something it must be TRUE....Ah Hem wait.. this runs every time.
}
```

USE THIS INSTEAD

```
try {
  $var = $wrapper->nid->raw();
} 
catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
  $var = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that isset() cannot be used on the result of a function call. Since a Boolean is returned with the following statement, I was able to verify that the wrapped element, in fact, had a value.

```
if ( $wrapper->field_media_alternate[0]->value() ) {
  //...valid logic...
} else {
  //...not valid logic...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

People often get this wrong. When you call isset on an entity metadata wrapper, you're checking whether the *entity bundle* supports that property. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the actual value of the field.

There isn't really an independent method for checking whether a value is set. You just have to evaluate value() or, preferably, raw(). (You can also call count() if it's a multi-value field, but raw() will return an empty array so it's not actually required.)

```
$w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
//Start by checking whether the node bundle supports field_entityref_myfield.
if (isset($w->field_entityref_myfield)) {
  //If we called value(), then that would cause the referenced entity
  //to be loaded, whereas raw() just gives us the entity_id if the value
  //is set, and Null if it isn't.
  if ($w->field_entityref_myfield->raw()) {
    //Do some things based on the entity-reference being set.
  } else {
    //Do some other things based on the entity-reference NOT being set.
  }
}
```

To reiterate, raw() is the value you should use to check whether a field exists. It's reliable and computationally cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my personal helper function to get a value from a potentialy not set chain of entity references:

```
function _get_wrapped_value_ifset($wentity, $field_chain){
  $root = $wentity;
  try{
    foreach ( $field_chain as $field_name ) {
      $root = $root->{$field_name};
    }
    return $root->value();
  }
  catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e){
    return null;
  }
}
```

$wentity is the wrapped entity , 
$field_chain is an array of field_names like so:

```
[
  'field_reference_from_the_wentity',
  'field_wanted_field_from_the_referenced_entity'
]
```

you may also do:

```
[
  'field_reference_from_the_wentity', 
  'field_reference_from_the_referenced_entity',
  ... 
  'field_wanted_field_from_the_N_referenced_entity'
]
```

it'll work !