# How to check if entity's property has a value

Tags: entities

How can I check if entity's property has a value? I don't think this is the "drupal way" to check it like this

```
$page_optimization->title->value() !== ''
```

Is there any method, something like $page_optimization->title->hasValue() etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entity metadata wrapper to check if fields are empty.

For example, you can check to see if a textfield is empty with the following. First create the wrapper:

```
// You need the entity type and entity id. 
$type = 'node'; $nid = 123; 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($type, $nid);
```

Then check to see if your text field is empty.

```
$value = $wrapper->field_my_text->value();
if (isset($value)) {
   // Entity has a non-null value for field_my_text, but it might be 0 or empty string. 
} if (!empty($value)) {
   // Entity has a value for field_my_text, and it is not 0, empty string, etc. 
}
```

For more examples see this excellent blog post - [death to field arrays](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper)!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the entity module, specifically the EntityMetadataWrapper class, there is no method of checking whether or not something has a value.  If a value returns empty you are essentially checking whether or not the value exists by getting an empty value.

For example a single value uses the EntityValueWrapper and only has one method and that is to return the value.  The EntityMetadataWrapper class has few public methods and none that returns whether or not a value is set.  If you wanted to extend one of the classes you could probably build your own method.

```
/**
 * Wraps a single value.
 */
class EntityValueWrapper extends EntityMetadataWrapper {

  /**
   * Overrides EntityMetadataWrapper#value().
   * Sanitizes or decode textual data if necessary.
   */
  public function value(array $options = array()) {
    $data = parent::value();
    if ($this->type == 'text' && isset($data)) {
      $info = $this->info + array('sanitized' => FALSE, 'sanitize' => 'check_plain');
      $options += array('sanitize' => FALSE, 'decode' => FALSE);
      if ($options['sanitize'] && !$info['sanitized']) {
        return call_user_func($info['sanitize'], $data);
      }
      elseif ($options['decode'] && $info['sanitized']) {
        return decode_entities(strip_tags($data));
      }
    }
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use isset:

```
if (isset($page_optimization->title) && $title = $page_optimization->title->value()) {
  // $page_optimization->title has value
  drupal_set_message($title);
}
```

that avoids a fatal error of referencing a non-existent entity wrapper property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use __isset() function like

```
$page_optimization->__isset('title');
```

You can get more info here
[Checking for existence for a field on an an entity_metadata_wrapper](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94748/checking-for-existence-for-a-field-on-an-an-entity-metadata-wrapper#)
[php overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Answer (score 1):

For those who land on this for **Drupal 8**, the way to do this is as follows

$entity->get('field_name')->isEmpty()

See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869575/how-do-you-check-if-a-field-is-empty-in-drupal-8

This comes from the

[Complex Data Interface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21ComplexDataInterface.php/function/ComplexDataInterface%3A%3AisEmpty/8.2.x) extended by [FieldItemInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemInterface.php/interface/FieldItemInterface/8.2.x) (Drupal API Doc Links)