# How to use conditional not to print a field if empty in user profile?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

As in node.tpl.php, I would like in user-profile.tpl.php to test if a field is empty or not to show my html.

I tried it :

```
<?php if (!empty($user_profile['field_myfield'])): ?>
<?php print render($user_profile['field_myfield']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it does not work.

Have you the solution?

Comment: Why bother testing it for empty. It will not render any html in any case if the field is empty, so just render it. If you wanted to perform some other action then you need to not test for empty on the field, but on the value property of the array of the field. There will always be an array structure, so the way you are testing in any case will not work.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? How to test for empty on the value property of the array of the field ?

Comment: Install Devel module then dpm($user_profile['field_myfield']). That will show you what the variable contains. You can then decide what to test.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using Entity Metadata Wrappers?

You can wrap the user profile using `$user_profile_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user_profile);`, and then you can find out if the field has a value with:

```
if (isset($user_profile_wrapper->field_myfield)) {}
```

This should tell you if the user profile HAS the field, and then you might use:

```
$value = $user_profile_wrapper->field_myfleid->value();
```

to actually get the value and test if it's empty or not.

Sources:

- https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers
- [Checking for existence for a field on an an entity_metadata_wrapper](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94748/checking-for-existence-for-a-field-on-an-an-entity-metadata-wrapper/)

Comment: Thanks thatblondeguy, i try to put this in user-profile.tpl.php, but i have an error : EntityMetadataWrapperException : `Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.`

Comment: Hmm, that's kind of weird because the only place that that particular error message comes up is when you use the `$wrapper->set()` function, and I thought you were just reading properties and fields on entities. Can you include your code that's throwing that exception?